# Xamarin Forms - Navigate to child of Tabbed Page

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I have a TabbedPage with 3 tabs, where I want to navigate directly to the 2nd content page (TagsListPage), but still keep my Tabbed header.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   
<TabbedPage
    x:Class="BradyRfidDemo.V1.MobileApp.Views.TabbedInventoryPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BradyRfidDemo.V1.MobileApp.Views"
    Title=" SCAN PAGE"
    Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false">

    <local:InventoryPage />
    <local:TagsListPage />
    <local:Transfer />

</TabbedPage>
```

TagsListPage:  (I removed most of the code to make it clean).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="BradyRfidDemo.V1.MobileApp.Views.TagList"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Title="TAGLIST"
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Color1}">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout >
 
            <Frame >
                <StackLayout 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label
                        x:Name="TagList"
                        Margin="0,10,0,0"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                       Text="TAGLIST" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

So I want to access from **another** form content page, directly the TagsListPage, and keep my tabbed header.
If I go to the main page, I get my tabbed header, but it goes to the first page (InventoryPage)

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new TabbedInventoryPage());
```

If I go directly to the TagListPage, then I get my page, but not the tabbed structure which I need as well.

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new TagsListPage());
```

I tried a lot of different things, but nothing worked so far, and this looks like a very simple thing to do.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: to change the active tab, set the `CurrentPage` property.  If you want to navigate **within** a tab, then wrap that tab's child in a `NavigationPage`.  Each tab can maintain it's own Navigation stack.

Comment: It is to navigate outside a tab.  So from a completely different page.

Comment: then you need to 1) navigate to the tabbed page, 2) activate the correct tab, 3) use that tab's navigation stack to navigate to the appropriate page

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: *How do you do that?*: 1) you are doing correctly with PushAsync TabbedInventoryPage. 2) google `xamarin forms TabbedPage set tab programmatically`. 3) google `xamarin forms navigation page`. If that doesn't show how to do it programmatically, then do an appropriate google related to that.